# Convert Unicode hex to decimals in PHP 7.4

Tags: php, unicode, hex

The following if-condition executes as expected:

```
    if (hexdec($range[0]) < $char && $char < hexdec($range[1])) {
```

however giving the following notice in PHP 7.4:

> Deprecated function: Invalid characters passed for attempted
> conversion, these have been ignored in

because as https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hexdec.php states:

> As of PHP 7.4.0 supplying any invalid characters is deprecated.

I don't have control over supplied characters - if they are valid or not. Any ideas on how to re-write the above code to avoid the `Deprecated function` notice?

Comment: Use a regular expression to check if all characters are in the `0-9a-z` range beforehand? Whether to then simply remove those, and proceed with checking the rest, or not perform the check at all - can’t tell you, because you did not explain the _purpose_ of this at all.

Comment: @04FS You mean in the `0-9a-f` range?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware uh, yes, of course :-) Typo.